# Unable to cast to Dictionary error on lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I have watched Alvinblox's egg hatching tutorial and FOR THE 3RD TIME there is an error :/
the error is "Unable to cast to Dictionary" It is at line 53 (the longest line)
Here is the code below if you can help me thank you so much!

```
local camera = workspace.Camera
local studio = workspace.Studio
local template = script.Parent.Pets.ScrollingFrame.Template
local scrollingFrame = script.Parent.Pets.ScrollingFrame

local function addToFrame(pet)
    local newTemplate = template:Clone()
    newTemplate.Name = pet.Name
    newTemplate.petName.Text = pet.Name
    newTemplate.Parent = scrollingFrame
    newTemplate.Visible = true
    local camera = Instance.new("Camera")
    local newPet = pet:Clone()
    newPet.Parent = newTemplate.ViewportFrame
    camera.CFrame = CFrame.new(newPet.PrimaryPart.Position + (newPet.PrimaryPart.CFrame.LookVector * 3), newPet.PrimaryPart.Position)
    camera.Parent = newTemplate.ViewportFrame
    newTemplate.ViewportFrame.CurrentCamera = camera
end

game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg.OnClientEvent:Connect(function (pet)
    addToFrame(pet)
    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    camera.CFrame = studio.CameraPart.CFrame
    wait(1.5)
    for i = 1,50,1 do
        studio["Egg Mesh"].Size = studio["Egg Mesh"].Size + Vector3.new(0.1,0.1,0.1)
        wait(0.01)
    end
    local explosion = Instance.new("Explosion")
    explosion.BlastRadius = 10
    explosion.BlastPressure = 0
    explosion.Position = studio["Egg Mesh"].Position
    explosion.ExplosionType = Enum.ExplosionType.NoCraters
    explosion.DestroyJointRadiusPercent = 0
    explosion.Parent = studio["Egg Mesh"]
    studio["Egg Mesh"].Transparency = 1
    local petClone = pet:Clone()
    for i,v in pairs(petClone:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("ParticleEmitter") then
            v.Enabled = true
        end
    end 
    petClone:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(studio["Egg Mesh"].Position, studio.CameraPart.Position))
    petClone.Parent = studio
    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
        2,
        Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce,
        Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
        0,
        false,
        0
    )
    local tween  = game:GetService("TweenService"):Create(camera, TweenInfo, {CFrame = CFrame.new(petClone.PrimaryPart.Positon + (petClone.PrimaryPart.CFrame.lookVector * 5)+Vector3.new(0,0.75,0)),petClone.PrimaryPart.Position})
    tween:Play()
    wait(5)
    for i,v in pairs(petClone:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("ParticleEmitter") then
            v.Enabled = false
        end
    end 
    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
    studio["Egg Mesh"].Transparency = 0
    studio["Egg Mesh"].Size = Vector3.new(4.732, 6, 4.732)
end)
```

Here is the fireserver code

```
local cost = 50
local petMoudle = require(game.ServerScriptService.BasicEggModule)
local prompt = workspace["Egg Holder"].Part.ProximityPrompt


prompt.Triggered:Connect(function (player)
    if player.leaderstats.Cash.Value >= cost then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - cost
        local pet = petMoudle.chooseRandomPet()
        print(pet.Name.." selected")
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient(player, pet)
    end
end)
```

Here is the module

```
local petMoudle = {}


petMoudle.Pets = {
    ["Legendary"] = {
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets["lil' demon"];
    };
    ["Rare"] = {
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets["Ice golem"];
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets["Light Bat"];
    };
    ["Uncommon"] = {
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets.Fox
    };
    ["Common"] = {
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets.Bunny;
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets.Mouse
    }
    
}   

petMoudle.rarities = {
    ["Legendary"] = 5;
    ["Rare"] = 15;
    ["Uncommon"] = 30;
    ["Common"] = 50
}

petMoudle.chooseRandomPet = function()
    local randomNumber = math.random(1, 100)
    local counter = 0
    for rarity, weight in pairs(petMoudle.rarities) do
        counter = counter + weight
        if randomNumber <= counter then
            local rarityTable = petMoudle.Pets[rarity]
            local chosenPet = rarityTable[math.random(1, #rarityTable)]
            
            return chosenPet
        end
    end
end


return petMoudle
```

Once again thank you if you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TweenService:Create function](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TweenService/Create) expects a dictionary for the last argument, and you have provided this (simplified):

```
{ CFrame = CFrame.new(...), petClone.PrimaryPart.Position }
```

The error you are getting is telling you that the table you have created has mixed keys, and that cannot be cast to just a dictionary. But all of this is because your actual issue was a misplaced close parenthesis. It's supposed to be...

```
CFrame.new(..., petClone.PrimaryPart.Position)
```

Now, let's fix it and break up this line into more readable parts...

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

local targetVector = petClone.PrimaryPart.Positon + (petClone.PrimaryPart.CFrame.lookVector * 5) + Vector3.new(0,0.75,0)
local lookVector = petClone.PrimaryPart.Position
local targetCframe = CFrame.new(targetVector, lookVector)
local propsToTween = { CFrame = targetCframe }

local tween  = TweenService:Create(camera, tweenInfo, propsToTween)
tween:Play()
```

Comment: Lua can have mixed key tables. For example this: `a = {foo = 5, 10}` evaluates fine on every version of Lua. It should be clarified that this is an error thrown by the function expecting non-numeric keys, and not by Lua.

Comment: Very good point, I'll clarify that.

Comment: There is another error which is "unable to cast dictionary to tweeninfo" at the tween = ... line

Comment: Found another typo. `TweenService:Create(camera, tweenInfo, propsToTween)` had tweenInfo incorrectly capitalized.